# Displaying input value on another page using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I need some help when it comes to display the text i sent using post method to another page.

**What I Need:**

Write some text in a textarea, if a checkbox is checked, every time the textarea value changes send the value to another page where I need to display it without refreshing the page.

Steps:

1. Check Checkbox -> Write text "Info"
2. First Page sent the text "Info" -> Second Page recived the text.
3. First Page modify text to "Random" -> Second Page text is changed to "Random"

**What I Have Managed To Do So Far:**

Verify if checkbox is checked, then send the text to the second page.

**Where I Am Stuck:**

I am stuck at displaying the text on the second page.

Javascript:

```
         var textval = "";
         var fereastra;
    function myPreview() {
        textval = $("#formid").val();
        $(".arata").html(textval);
        if(document.getElementById('previz').checked) {
            $.post("testprev.php", {text: textval})
        }

    }
    }
    function verifica(){

        if(document.getElementById('previz').checked) {

            fereastra = window.open("testprev.php","fereastra");
            $(".arata").fadeIn(1000);

        }
        else {
            fereastra.close("testprev.php");
            $(".arata").hide(1000);
        }
    }
```

HTML/PHP - First page:

```
<form method="post"
      action="testprev.php"
      enctype="multipart/form-data"
      id="prevform">
  <textarea name="preview"
      id="formid"
      value=""
      rows="25" columns="20"
      onkeyup="myPreview()">
  </textarea>
  <input type="checkbox" 
      id="previz"
      onclick="verifica()" />
  Previzualizeaza
</form>
```

HTML/PHP - Second page

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['text'])) 
  {
    $text = $_POST['text'];
?>

<?php
    echo $text;
  }
?>
```

Comment: So the second page is actually opened in other browser tab/window? I'm really not sure what are you meaning it

Comment: This way you can not do it.

Comment: @A.Wolff the second page is another window in the same browser.

Comment: @void What's they way to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think with this approach you can get the data by POST. But their is a tricky way infact with which you can do that.

When you are opening the link just pass the `value of textarea` as a get parameter. And in the PHP file fetch it.

Change you `verifica` function by this.

```
function verifica(){
        textval = $("#formid").val();
        if(document.getElementById('previz').checked) {
            fereastra = window.open("testprev.php?text="+textval,"fereastra");
            $(".arata").fadeIn(1000);

        }
        else {
            fereastra.close("testprev.php?text="+textval);
            $(".arata").hide(1000);
        }
    }
```

And in **second page PHP** just do

```
<?php

    if(isset($_GET['text'])){
    $text = $_GET['text'];
    echo $text; } 
?>
```

Comment: Is there another method apart from GET ?

Comment: You can store the data in database/cookie and fetch them.

Comment: No need for database is something like "Post Preview" - Cookie sounds ok but i can't find a way to do or i can't think of one.

Comment: Please post it as a new thread. It confuses other readers. I will answer the question their. If it solves your problem please consider voting it up and marking it as correct answer. :)

Comment: Their is a tick near top left of my answer. Please check it to mark it as correct answer.

Comment: I know how stackoverflow works , i were just stuck , by they way thanks i will use GET method. Answer accepted.